# Set `REPORT_TIME_ZONE` parameter from a database record

Tags: oracle11g, jasper-reports, jasperserver

Our DB has a table for report recipients, complete with their preferred timezones.

**How can I use this column as the value for the `REPORT_TIME_ZONE` parameter in the report?**

Workarounds I have tried/thought of:

- `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='Europe/Zurich';` but [guilio says no](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/521167/set-session-time-zone-query-timestamp)
- `def recipientTzCode = (SELECT TIMEZONE_CODE FROM REPORT_RECIPIENTS WHERE RECIPIENT_ID=$P{recipientId});` at the top, but this seems to be the same as before
- `SELECT...FROM_TZ( CAST(created_at AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE (SELECT TIMEZONE_CODE FROM REPORT_RECIPIENTS WHERE RECIPIENT_ID=$P{recipientId})...` but this doesn't work with `GROUP BY` statements

**[Clarification Edit]**
I need to do this inside the confines of the Report (*.jrxml) and a standalone Jaspersoft Server instance. Outside software is cheating ;-)

Comment: Why doesn't the third option work with group-by? Can't you join to get the parameter instead of having a subquery?

Comment: When you call the report (either through rest or embedding with url) you can pass the userTimezone parameter e.g.

Comment: @AlexPoole I suppose so, but that turns into a lot of `JOIN`s...plan B?

Comment: Not sure I understand your edit - your *don't* want to do this in SQL? And not sure why there would be a lot of joins, rather than just one, or what the group-by issue is; perhaps a more complete example would clarify the situation?

Comment: @AlexPoole sorry, that edit was to eliminate external software, not in reference to SQL (which the report contains :). For non-trivial queries with lots of `JOIN`ed (`GROUP BY`) sub-queries this results in lots of `JOIN`ed (`JOIN`ed `GROUP BY`) expressions. It's a great suggestion, but I'm hoping the repetition isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the report (either through rest or embedding with url) you can pass the userTimezone parameter e.g.

https://server/jasperserver-pro/flow.html?_flowId=dashboardRuntimeFlow&dashboardResource=%2Forganizations%2Forganization_1%2Freports%2FREPORT&userTimezone=Europe/Zurich

The link given is a link to the report in Jasperserver. By default the server will take the timezone specified when you log in. You can override this by redirecting to the url with the &userTimezone=Europe/Zurich at the end.

Or I believe if you add a parameter to the report (in iReport) called userTimezone you can add this as an input control on the server with the timezones you want and input this when the report is called from the server.

Comment: Added a clarification to the question. How would I set that query parameter  from Jasper Server?